# First Expo project throwing error after npm start

Tags: react-native, expo

I followed instructions to install Expo on my Windows 10 machine. I'm running `node` version `10.14.0` on my machine.

After I issued `expo init` command and created the first project, running `npm start` shows a message that reads:

> This command requires Expo CLI. Do you want to install it globally
>   [Y/n]?

Strange thing is that I'd already installed the latest version of `expo-cli` globally. Running `expo-cli --version` in the project folder gives me the version of `expo-cli` which is `2.5.0`.

From here, it gets worse. No matter what I choose, I get the following error:
[image]

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same issue, first run:

```
npm i expo-cli
```

then:

```
npm start
```

Worked for me

Comment: Thanks...Worked for me too..is it for what?

Answer (score 0):

first type:

```
npm i expo-cli
```

then type :

```
   expo start
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. For a better answer, please format the commands as code and explain why this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the same error, so I went to the expo documentation (https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/get-started/installation/), to see the error.

First I logged into the expo:

```
expo login --username -u [username] --password -p [password]
```

and then I checked if I was logged in:

```
expo whoami
```

Second I followed this help that I found on stackOverflow:
[How to resolve the error on 'react-native start'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58120990/how-to-resolve-the-error-on-react-native-start/58199866#58199866)

Hope this helps.