# How to resolve the error on 'react-native start'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-cli, metro-bundler

1. I just installed node.js & cli

   - installed node.js
   - installed react-native-cli

     ```
     npm -g react-native-cli
     ```
2. And created a 'new project'.

   ```
   react-native init new_project
   ```
3. and inside that 'new_project' directory, I tired to see if metro bundler works well.

   ```
   react-native start
   ```
4. But the command gave me following error and metro is not starting.
   Any clue for fixing this error?
   (I'm using windows 10 OS.)

   - command : `C:\projects\new_proj>react-native start`

     > error Invalid regular expression: 
     >   /(.\fixtures.|node_modules[]react[]dist[].|website\node_modules.|heapCapture\bundle.js|.\tests.)$/: Unterminated character class. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
     >   SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(.\fixtures.|node_modules[]react[]dist[].|website\node_modules.|heapCapture\bundle.js|.\tests.)$/: Unterminated character class
     >   at new RegExp ()
     >   at blacklist (D:\projects\new_proj\node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js:34:10)
     >   at getBlacklistRE (D:\projects\new_proj\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\loadMetroConfig.js:69:59)
     >   at getDefaultConfig (D:\projects\new_proj\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\loadMetroConfig.js:85:20)
     >   at load (D:\projects\new_proj\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\loadMetroConfig.js:121:25)
     >   at Object.runServer [as func] (D:\projects\new_proj\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\server\runServer.js:82:58)
     >   at Command.handleAction (D:\projects\new_proj\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\cliEntry.js:160:21)
     >   at Command.listener (D:\projects\new_proj\node_modules\commander\index.js:315:8)
     >   at Command.emit (events.js:210:5)
     >   at Command.parseArgs (D:\projects\new_proj\node_modules\commander\index.js:651:12)

Comment: Like they stated `Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.` Perhaps you forgot to escape a backslash. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639339/javascript-unterminated-character-class . Cannot say without more details.

Comment: Just in case metro-config doesn't exist in node_modules for you then check my answer below.

Answer (score 386):

I just got a similar error for the first time today. It appears in `\node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js`, there is an invalid regular expression that needed changed. I changed the first expression under `sharedBlacklist` from:

```js
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

to:

```js
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I made changes as you said and it works now. Do I have to modify this on every project or is there a way to apply this globally?

Comment: Thank you much! it worked fine. Could you explain the reason?

Comment: This solve my problem too but i understand why this happened, someone know the why?

Comment: Got some other answer from the query on Github. - 'It's caused by node v12.11.0, downgrade to v12.10.0 will solve it.' It was from Leo.Lei. And I also need to see if it works or not.

Comment: Excellent fix! Thanks a lot. React Native seems like such buggy ride, from corrupt npm cache, to PERM errors. It's taken me two day just to install.

Comment: /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,                       Just this line needs change

Comment: Thanks a lot! It save me lots of time. I've just upgraded my Node.js from v8.x.x. to v12.13.0 in this night and then this error suddenly which leads to app start failure ... didn't aware it's cause by this bug without this post ...

Comment: I have var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules\/react\/dist\/.*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
as this, still its not working.

Comment: I'm getting an error after performing this: error: unknown option '--assetPlugins' Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
Error: Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
at ChildProcess(/@expo/xdl@57.9.15/src/Project.js:1918:16).....  my jest- expo version is 36.0.1 and my react-native, expo version is 36.0.0

Comment: Works more than charm. This is the second project I am bumping into this error, and this is the answer that has helped me twice.

Comment: step 1. node_modules/metro/src/blacklist.js
step 2. replace code

Answer (score 145):

This is caused by node v12.11.0 due to the way it deals regular location there two ways to solve this problem

Method I

You can downgrade to node v12.10.0 this will apply the correct way to deal with parsing error

Method II

You can correctly  terminate the regular expression in you case by changing the file located a:

`\node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js`

From:

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

To:

```
 var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

Comment: A pull request was submitted back in October: https://github.com/facebook/metro/commit/7c6f30b592b2fb23cee55b54f1aa4b7a522dec18

Answer (score 36):

It is due to mismatched blacklist file configuration.

To resolve that,

1. We have to move to the project folder.
2. Open `\node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js`
3. Replace the following.

From

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

To

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

Answer (score 29):

## [Quick Answer]

There are a problem with Metro using some NPM and Node versions.

You can fix the problem changing some code in the file `\node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js` .

Search this variable:

```js
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

and change to this:

```js
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

> Please note that if you run an npm install or a yarn install you need to change the code again.

Comment: Note that if you're using an old version of react-native (eg. 0.51.0), the file to be changed is instead at: `.\node_modules\metro-bundler\src\blacklist.js`

Answer (score 26):

You have two solutions:

either you downgrade node to V12.10.0 or you can modify this file for every project you will create.

**node_modules/metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist.js**
Change this:

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

to this:

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

Answer (score 25):

### I don't have metro-config in my project, now what?

I have found that in pretty older project there is no `metro-config` in `node_modules`. If it is the case with you, then,

> Go to node_modules/metro-bundler/src/blacklist.js

And do the same step as mentioned in other answers, i.e.

Replace

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
    /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/,
    /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
    /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
    /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

with

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
    /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
    /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
    /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
    /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

P.S. I faced the same situation in a couple of projects so thought sharing it might help someone.

**Edit**

As per comment by @beltrone the file might also exist in,

> node_modules\metro\src\blacklist.js

Comment: Did help, but the file in my 360 init is in `MyProject\node_modules\metro\src\blacklist.js`. Cheers.

Answer (score 20):

I got same problem.

"error Invalid regular expression: /(.*\**fixtures**\.*|node_modules[\]react[\]dist[\].*|website\node_modules\.*|heapCapture\bundle.js|.*\**tests**\.*)$/: Unterminated character class."

Change the regular expression in `\node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js`

**From**

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

**To**

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

This change resolved my error.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem I altered the E:\NodeJS\ReactNativeApp\ExpoTest\node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js in my project

from

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
 /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
 /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

to

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

this worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 7):

A [PR](https://github.com/facebook/metro/pull/468) with a fix has been merged in the [metro](https://github.com/facebook/metro) repository. Now we just need to wait until the next release. For now the best option is to downgrade to NodeJS `v12.10.0`. As [Brandon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12273899/brandon-gohsman) pointed out, modifying anything in `node_modules/` isa really bad practice and will not be a final solution.

Answer (score 7):

### The solution is simple, but temporary...

Note that if you run an `npm install` or a `yarn install` you need to change the code again!

So, how can we run this automatically?

### Permanent Solution

To do this "automagically" after installing your node modules, you can use `patch-package`.

1. Fix the `metro-config` file, solving the error:

The file appears in `\node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js`.

Edit from:

```js
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

To:

```js
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

2. Then, generate a permanent patch file:

`npx patch-package metro-config`

3. In your `package.json` trigger the patch:

```
"scripts": {
+  "postinstall": "npx patch-package"
}
```

**All done!** Now this patch will be made at every `npm install` / `yarn install`.

Thanks to https://github.com/ds300/patch-package

Comment: It is most reasonable answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/453

for who still get this error without official patch in react-native , expo

use yarn and add this setting into package.json

```
{
  ...
  "resolutions": {
    "metro-config": "bluelovers/metro-config-hotfix-0.56.x"
  },
 ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Go to

> \node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js

and replace this

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
/node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/,
/website\/node_modules\/.*/,
/heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
/.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

to

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
/node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
/website\/node_modules\/.*/,
/heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
/.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

> This is not a best practice and my recommendation is: downgrade node version into 12.9 OR update metro-config since they are fixing the Node issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can go to...

\node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js and change...

```
var sharedBlacklist = [   /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/,  
/website\/node_modules\/.*/,   /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,  
/.*\/__tests__\/.*/ ];
```

for this:

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

Answer (score 3):

I have just update package.json to change from

```
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz"
```

to

```
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz"
```

It seems that the problem won't occur in **sdk-36** !!

My node version is **v12.16.0** and os is **win10**.

Answer (score 2):

All mentioned comments above are great, sharing the path that worked with me for this Blacklist file that need to be edited:

> > > "Your project name\node_modules\metro-bundler\src" File name "blacklist.js"

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue today with a project that was built on an old version of node, I just installed node `v12.9.0` and the problem was resolved. I use `nvm` to easily downgrade node versions.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, I don't modify files within `node_modules/` (or anything which does not get committed as part of a repository) as the next clean, build or update will regress them. I definitely have done so in the past and it has bitten me a couple of times. But this does work as a short-term/local dev fix until/unless  `metro-config` is updated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Fix it by install metro-config of the latest version (0.57.0 for now) they had fixed the problem:

npm install metro-config

you can remove it later, after react-native guys update module versions

Comment: That doesn't help to me.

Answer (score 1):

I found the regexp.source changed from `node v12.11.0`, maybe the new `v8` engine caused.
see more on https://github.com/nodejs/node/releases/tag/v12.11.0.

```sh
D:\code\react-native>nvm use 12.10.0
Now using node v12.10.0 (64-bit)

D:\code\react-native>node
Welcome to Node.js v12.10.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/.source
'node_modules[\\/\\\\]react[\\/\\\\]dist[\\/\\\\].*'
> /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/.source.replace(/\//g, path.sep)
'node_modules[\\\\\\\\]react[\\\\\\\\]dist[\\\\\\\\].*'
>
(To exit, press ^C again or ^D or type .exit)
>

D:\code\react-native>nvm use 12.11.0
Now using node v12.11.0 (64-bit)

D:\code\react-native>node
Welcome to Node.js v12.11.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/.source
'node_modules[/\\\\]react[/\\\\]dist[/\\\\].*'
> /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/.source.replace(/\//g, path.sep)
'node_modules[\\\\\\]react[\\\\\\]dist[\\\\\\].*'
>
(To exit, press ^C again or ^D or type .exit)
>

D:\code\react-native>nvm use 12.13.0
Now using node v12.13.0 (64-bit)

D:\code\react-native>node
Welcome to Node.js v12.13.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/.source
'node_modules[/\\\\]react[/\\\\]dist[/\\\\].*'
> /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/.source.replace(/\//g, path.sep)
'node_modules[\\\\\\]react[\\\\\\]dist[\\\\\\].*'
>
(To exit, press ^C again or ^D or type .exit)
>

D:\code\react-native>nvm use 13.3.0
Now using node v13.3.0 (64-bit)

D:\code\react-native>node
Welcome to Node.js v13.3.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/.source
'node_modules[/\\\\]react[/\\\\]dist[/\\\\].*'
> /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/.source.replace(/\//g, path.sep)
'node_modules[\\\\\\]react[\\\\\\]dist[\\\\\\].*'
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Today I ran into exactly this issue, but none of these answers above were applicable for me as locally changing/patching node_modules or adding resolutions handled by yarn only will never be a solution for me, be it short-term or whatever.

Not surprisingly at all, package.json just needed to get some updated dependency versions, so I hit the cli, changed to the project directory where package.json was located and these lines did the job then:

- npm install -g npm-check-updates
- ncu -u
- npm install

The first line globally installs a tool which simply lists all (dev-)deps provided by package.json which you could upgrade. The second command automagically adapts the version numbers within package.json. The last line reinstalls node-modules - using "yarn" instead of "npm install" is perfectly fine as well.

Now react-native works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Here's my solution

run: `npm update --filter`

This command would update all the necessary dependencies to have your react-native app running

next

run: `npm start  // expo start`

Answer (score 1):

step 1. node_modules/metro/src/blacklist.js
step 2. replace code

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
/node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
/website\/node_modules\/.*/,
/heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
/.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes such issues can occur due to broken dependencies. There, it can be resolved by updating packages.

```
npx npm-check-updates -u
npm i
```