# "Getting Started" Guide for React Native Not Working with Android Device

Tags: android, react-native

I've been trying to get the [basic React Native program](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started) up and running on my Windows PC, and cannot get it to load on my Pixel 3 which is connected through USB. I've done a fresh install of Node.js to 12.13.1. Here's what I get when I do `npx react-native run-android`

```
PS C:\Users\davidc\Working\AwesomeProject> npx react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 864 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :app:installDebug
03:53:33 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config
03:53:33 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on '891X0457A' : EOF hit. Read: -1
03:53:33 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Pixel 3 - 10' for app:debug
03:53:33 D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto device '891X0457A'
03:53:33 D/Device: Uploading file onto device '891X0457A'
03:53:33 D/ddms: Reading file permision of C:\Users\davidc\Working\AwesomeProject\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk as: rwx------
03:53:34 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
03:53:37 V/ddms: execute 'pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on '891X0457A' : EOF hit. Read: -1
03:53:37 V/ddms: execute: returning
03:53:37 V/ddms: execute: running rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
03:53:37 V/ddms: execute 'rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on '891X0457A' : EOF hit. Read: -1
03:53:37 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installed on 1 device.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 32s
27 actionable tasks: 27 executed
info Connecting to the development server...
8081
info Starting the app on "891X0457A"...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.awesomeproject/.MainActivity }
PS C:\Users\davidc\Working\AwesomeProject>
```

That's all I can get it to do. My phone says it's unable to load script, and to make sure metro server is running or index.android.bundle has been packaged correctly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the issue I was having stemmed from metro having some code which does not play nicely with the way the latest node version handles RegExs. A temporary solution can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58120990/how-to-resolve-the-error-on-react-native-start/58122821#58122821). Once that was fixed, I was able to run the code [provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows/44476757#44476757) to build the index.android.bundle which had been missing.