# metro-config node_modules not found in react-native project

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, react-native, node-modules

I am serving "react-native start" command in my project and it gives me below error.

> Invalid regular expression: /(.*\__fixtures__\.*|node_modules[\]react[\]dist[\].*|website\node_modules\.*|heapCapture\bundle.js|.*\__tests__\.*)$/: Unterminated character class

[I have found above problem solution here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58120990/how-to-resolve-the-error-on-react-native-start#)

But the problem is when i am trying to navigate to `"node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js"` this path there is no such folder named `"metro-config"`.

I did remove the node_modules and re-install them again but the problem is still same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find `blacklist.js` file in this location as well, `node_modules/metro/src/blacklist.js`. Make same changes in that file.

Replace

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

with

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

I fixed it just last night.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution->To find metro-config go to you window search bar and type metro-config or directly type blacklist.js and you will find the exact location of file