# React Native problem with finding module blacklist in metro-config

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler, msal-react

I'm trying to use this [library](https://github.com/stashenergy/react-native-msal/issues?page=2&q=). I cloned the code, ran `npm install` and then ran `react-native run-android`. As a result I got an error `Cannot find module 'metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist'`. I looked it up, and found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59099614/5587350) that suggest
to change the content of the `blacklist.js` file because of faulty regex.
However, I looked at the path suggested in the answer `metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist` but it didn't contain any `blacklist.js` files. I also looked at other paths but still didn't find anything with the name `blacklist.js`.
How can I fix this issue and get the library working?

Node version: v14.17.0

React native version: 0.64.2

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in expo-yarn-workspace with the same react-native version.
I fixed it by find where `'metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist'` is call and replace it
by `'metro-config/src/defaults/exclusionList'` because  it's been renamed.

https://github.com/facebook/metro/blob/a94200229df4e7f3a9549665142d4ad4b8d32de5/packages/metro-config/src/defaults/exclusionList.js

https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/453

Let me know if it works for you !