# Unable to load script.Make sure you're either running a Metro server

Tags: react-native

[i stuck with this error when i try npx npx react-native run-android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RS1yb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I got fixed this problem using the below steps.

cd MyApp

I was getting some blacklist.js some character issue. For that I referred this link and replaced sharedBlacklist character set.

([How to resolve the error on 'react-native start'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58120990/how-to-resolve-the-error-on-react-native-start/58122821#58122821))

Next, I ran the below code snippet to address the bundle issue.( Ref Link :

https://medium.com/@adityasingh_32512/solved-unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-bdc5e3a3d5ff)

react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

react-native run-android
Then, it started working.
Hope this helps.