# react-native init MyProject --version 0.58.6 but every time i do this , there comes an error as follows

Tags: react-native, npm

i am trying to init a new react native project using the command react-native init MyProject --version 0.58.6
but every time i do this , there comes an error as follows -
Done in 80.32s.

> D:\MyProject\node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js:34
> return new RegExp(
> ^
>
> SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression:
> /(.*\**fixtures**\.*|node_modules[\]react[\]dist[\].*|website\node_modules\.*|heapCapture\bundle.js|.*\**tests**\.*)$/:
> Unterminated character class
> at new RegExp ()
> at blacklist (D:\MyProject\node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js:34:10)
> at getBlacklistRE (D:\MyProject\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\util\Config.js:56:10)
> at Object. (D:\MyProject\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\util\Config.js:71:20)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
> at Module._compile (D:\MyProject\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:99:24)
> at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
> at Object.newLoader [as .js] (D:\MyProject\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:104:7)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)

After building dependencies is done

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is the bug in the old version of react-native I also have suffered from it sometimes, I have solved the same problem with the StackOverflow answer:

[How to resolve the error on 'react-native start'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58120990/how-to-resolve-the-error-on-react-native-start)