# Warning: The packages use deprecated "rnpm" config and node not working

Tags: react-native, node-modules

I have cloned a project from github, after using yarn to add packages and run, the node just shows a warning:

> The following packages use deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release

The node turns off immediately (in the photo) and and turn off immediately.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The node module turn off immediately, you can run yarn start or npx start, it will open node independence, and you can see the error. That is it:

> error Invalid regular expression: /(.\fixtures.|node_modules[]react[]dist[].|website\node_modules.|heapCapture\bundle.js|.\tests.)$/: Unterminated character class. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details. SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(.\fixtures.|node_modules[]react[]dist[].|website\node_modules.|heapCapture\bundle.js|.\tests.)$/: Unterminated character class at new RegExp () at blacklist (D:\projects\new_proj\node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js:34:10) at getBlacklistRE (D:\projects\new_proj\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\loadMetroConfig.js:69:59) at getDefaultConfig (D:\projects\new_proj\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\loadMetroConfig.js:85:20) at load (D:\projects\new_proj\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\loadMetroConfig.js:121:25) at Object.runServer [as func] (D:\projects\new_proj\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\server\runServer.js:82:58) at Command.handleAction (D:\projects\new_proj\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\cliEntry.js:160:21) at Command.listener (D:\projects\new_proj\node_modules\commander\index.js:315:8) at Command.emit (events.js:210:5) at Command.parseArgs (D:\projects\new_proj\node_modules\commander\index.js:651:12)

This problem is caused by node v12.11.0. You can find the solution in there:

> [How to resolve the error on 'react-native start'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58120990/how-to-resolve-the-error-on-react-native-start)